# How to check if a two dimensional array includes a string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, dynamic-arrays

I have a two dimensional array `arr[cols][rows]`.
I want to know if the cols contains a string "hello".
How can I check that using `.includes("hello")` method.

Please note that I am trying to check this inside a loop with counter `i`. So I have to do something like `arr[i][0].includes("hello");`

Comment: and did you do that? what do you get?

Comment: I assume you want to know if `[col]` contained `"hello"` in any of the `[row`]? You add a flag in your `j` loop (assuming you used `i` for col and `j` for row.)

Comment: Add more info such as - does sub-arrays have uniform length? How many dimensions have to be supported?

Comment: Yes, sub-arrays have uniform length. 2 dimensions have to be supported which means, there is an array that contains arrays which in turn contains two items each.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use `array.prototype.some` along with `array.prototype.includes`. It shoud be:

```js
var datas= [
  ["aaa", "bbb"],
  ["ddd", "eee"]
];

function exists(arr, search) {
    return arr.some(row => row.includes(search));
}

console.log(exists(datas, 'ddd'));
console.log(exists(datas, 'xxx'));
```

Comment: This worked. Can you explain what is happening inside the exists function?

Comment: As stated on MDN here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), The `some()` method tests whether at least one element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function. Which means that the array will pass the test (returning true) if each row passes its test, which is what the `row.includes(search)` does, it returns true if the row includes the search query.

Hope this helps.