# array .includes() giving unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a very simple array and am checking to see if it .includes() a value. But it is not returning the result I expect.

```
var myArray = [['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'], ['shen', 'Shenandoah National Park']];

var myItem = ['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'];

myArray.includes(myItem);   //returns false
```

Why is `myArray.inclues(myItem)` returning false?  This seems like the simplest thing in the world. It should return true.

Comment: Because `['noca'] === ['noca']` is `false`. These are two distinct arrays in memory. You can't compare arrays this way.

Comment: It is quite sneaky about looking simple, but not actually being the most simple =). This is a good question and hopefully this helps others!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking if an array contains another array is tricky. As I said in the comments, `['noca'] === ['noca']` returns `false` because these are two distinct arrays.

On the other hand, `JSON.stringify(['noca']) === JSON.stringify(['noca'])` returns `true` because it compares two strings, so you can use that :

```js
var myArray = [['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'], ['shen', 'Shenandoah National Park']];
var myItem = ['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'];

const checkContains = (parent, child) => parent.some(arr => JSON.stringify(arr)===JSON.stringify(child))

console.log( checkContains(myArray, myItem) )
console.log( checkContains(myArray, ["test"]) )
console.log( checkContains(myArray, ["noca"]) ) // No false positive (works as intended)
```

Comment: This is also a good approach. I would use either this or the answer I posted. Both will give you the same result. This one could be a little faster because it has a lower complexity, though I am unsure of the performance of JSON.stringify.

Comment: Currently, it's being stringified for every parent's element, which means if the parent contains 100 elements, the comparison array will be stringified 100 times, which is obviously a waste of resources. I would optimize it by caching `JSON.stringify(child)`. It's a wee bit more code.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I think .some will return as soon as it is successful, so while its worst case is pretty bad, the average case could be much better.

Answer (score 3):

The following is adopted from this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48538239/2096053

```js
var datas= [
  ["aaa", "bbb"],
  ["ddd", "eee"]
];

function exists(arr, search) {
    return arr.some(row => 
        Array.isArray(row) &&
        Array.isArray(search) &&
        row.length === search.length &&
        row.every((val, index) => val === search[index])
)
};

console.log(exists(datas, ['aaa', 'bbb'])); // TRUE
console.log(exists(datas, ['aaa']));        // FALSE
console.log(exists(datas, ['xxx']));        // FALSE
console.log(exists(datas, 'xxx'));          // FALSE
```

You need to use a combination of `some` and `includes` to properly go over the array.

I have updated this answer to search on arrays.

Comment: From what I understand, OP wants to check if `datas` contains `["aaa", "bbb"]`. They're trying to do `myArray.includes(['noca', 'North Cascades National Park']);`

Comment: @JeremyThille I updated the answer to work with arrays =)

Comment: Works... in most cases. But it also returns false positives. `exists(datas, ['aaa'])` returns `true`. You have to `row => search.every(v => row.includes(v)) && row.every(v => search.includes(v))`. But that's a lot of array traversing.

Comment: @JeremyThille You are correct, I made it a bit better to handle this and also not error out on non-array searches.

Comment: Fair enough :) Now it works indeed. Have an upvote

Answer (score 2):

This is an expected behaviour, because array is an object and it is referenced. So, your array element and actual element to compare will not be equal and `Array.prototype.includes()` will return `false`.

If you try following, it will return `true`.

```
var myItem = ['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'];

var myArray = [myItem, ['shen', 'Shenandoah National Park']];

myArray.includes(myItem);   //returns true
```

Comment: It's a nice explanation, but it doesn't solve the actual problem. What if `myArray` does not include `myItem` ?

Comment: To solve this problem, basically you need to serialize your target element using `JSON.stringify()` or Lodash's `cloneDeep` method. And you can use `Array.prototype.some()` by comparing each serialized array element with your serialized  target element.
`var myItem = ['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'];

var myArray = [['noca', 'North Cascades National Park'], ['shen', 'Shenandoah National Park']];

myArray.some(el => JSON.stringify(el) === JSON.stringify(myItem));   //returns true
`

Comment: Yep, this should have been your answer... while you were typing this, I posted it as an answer myself :)

Answer (score 1):

You are not using it correctly. References between arrays are not the same.

Check doc: [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

You should iterate over arrays and use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for example.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. You're just pointing out at resources and giving links.

Comment: @JeremyThille, good point. Will do it better next time.